# What could be wrong here?

Tags: java

Can anyone give me what could be wrong here?

```
    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class TopWordsFinder {

      /**
       * Map of <word length, <word content, count in text>> Use some different, or
       * even multiple data structures if it makes more sense to you.
       */
      Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> wordsByLength = new HashMap<>();

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TopWordsFinder().findTopWords();
      }

      private void findTopWords() {
        readWords(); // Read words to data structure
        printTopWords(); // Print words from data structure
      }

      // Reads words from file and stores in some data structure
      // Make sure to check the definition of word in context of this puzzle in
      // class javadoc
   private void readWords() {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(TopWordsFinder.class.getResourceAsStream("c:/book-text.txt"));
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder("");
        try{
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                char c = (char) in.read();
                if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)){
                    if(Character.isUpperCase(c)){
                        c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
                    }
                    word.append(c);
                }else{
                    saveWord(word.toString());
                    word.delete(0, word.length()-1);// Reset the sequence
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        }
    }
private void printTopWords() {
        Integer[] lengths = wordsByLength.keySet().toArray(new Integer[wordsByLength.keySet().size()]);
        Arrays.sort(lengths);
        for(int i = lengths.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            for(String word : wordsByLength.get(lengths[i]).keySet()){
                if(wordsByLength.get(lengths[i]).get(word) >= 3){
                    System.out.println("Sõna: "+word+" sõna pikkus: "+word.length()+" kordusi: "+wordsByLength.get(lengths[i]).get(word));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

 private void saveWord(String word) {
    // FILL IN HERE: Store word in data structure you chose
        if(wordsByLength.get(word.length()) == null){
            wordsByLength.put(word.length(), new HashMap<String, Integer>());
        }
        if(wordsByLength.get(word.length()) == null){
            wordsByLength.get(word.length()).put(word, 1);
        }else{
            int n = wordsByLength.get(word.length()).get(word);
            wordsByLength.get(word.length()).put(word, ++n);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my java work, but I'm getting `Error: java.io.IOException: Stream closed`.

Comment: Please post the code here and not a link to it and also explain what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I don't know how to post normally text here

Comment: Where do you get that error ?

Comment: in this line:   char c = (char) in.read();

Answer (score 1):

Here is your IO exception

```
}catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Error: "+e);
 }
```

Your  `char c = (char) in.read();` can throw it
when either the stream itself is corrupted or some error occurred during reading the data i.e. Security Exceptions, Permission Denied etc and/or a set of Exceptions which are derived from IOEXception.

To know it better you should use `System.out.println("Error: " +e.getMessage())` in your `catch block`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you are not closing the stream. I would expect this in a finally block... I'm not able to locate this block.

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(TopWordsFinder.class.getResourceAsStream("c:/book-text.txt"));
```

Something like

```
finally
{
    in.close();
}
```

Check out here for more details: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=8

Answer (score 0):

My guess is The problem is in `in.avaialble()` method.

from the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#available%28%29)

> IOException occurs in this method if this input stream has been closed
>   by invoking its close() method, or an I/O error occurs.

but you haven't close the stream. so my guess is the problem is in the line

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(TopWordsFinder.class.getResourceAsStream("c:/book-text.txt"));
```

check if your file path is ok or is there any other problem in this line.

and always close the stream after completing the task ( prefereable in `finally` block)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use a Scanner instead, your code would be easier to read like this

```
private void readWords() {
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("c:/book-text.txt");
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
  try {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      String word = scanner.next();
      if (word != null) {
        saveWord(word.toLowerCase());
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this, and now i am getting these: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TopWordsFinder.saveWord(TopWordsFinder.java:74)
 at TopWordsFinder.readWords(TopWordsFinder.java:47)
 at TopWordsFinder.findTopWords(TopWordsFinder.java:24)
 at TopWordsFinder.main(TopWordsFinder.java:19)

Comment: Edited to add a check for null. What is in your file?

Comment: It is just regular ebook, Task is to search longest word and how many times i get this

Answer (score 0):

You should use:-

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("c:/book-text.txt");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error message from the following try-catch block

```
}catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Error: "+e);
 }
```

Reason: You did not check if the file was opened properly. 
Put the code to open the file into a try-catch block and if the file is not opened properly:

```
private void readWords() {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream in = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/book-text.txt"));
            in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return; // unable to open file, so should not proceed further in
                    // readWords
        }
```

Also, you need to fix the code in `saveWord` method because this line null check is not proper:

```
if(wordsByLength.get(word.length()) == null){
}
if(wordsByLength.get(word.length()) == null){
} else {}
```

It should be:

```
private void saveWord(String word) {
    // FILL IN HERE: Store word in data structure you chose
    if (wordsByLength.get(word.length()) == null) {
        wordsByLength.put(word.length(), new HashMap<String, Integer>());
        wordsByLength.get(word.length()).put(word, 1);
    } else {
        int n = wordsByLength.get(word.length()).get(word);
        wordsByLength.get(word.length()).put(word, ++n);
    }
}
```